# Is this way of rewriting the sentence "This is the first time I've ...." correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

If we start with the sentence:

> "This is the first time I've touched a dolphin."

It can be rewritten in these ways.

> 1) This is my first time to touch a dolphin.
>
> 2) This is my first time touching a dolphin.

Some textbooks say that sentence 1) is wrong, but I see this kind of sentence a lot in textbooks in my country. Also I don't see sentence 2) very often. I'd like to know if I can use either or both of these two sentences instead of the original sentence.

Comment: I agree with your books about 1) being wrong. I have no problem with 2). It makes sense that you don't see it very often, though, because you'd only say it in that tense **while you were touching the dolphin**, and it's hard to write while you pet a dolphin. :^) Later, when an author would recount the experience, she would switch to the past tense: "That was my first time touching a dolphin."

Comment: @J.R.  It's clear now, but I'd like to make sure again.  I'm leaving for the US in a few days and I'm saying to my friend, "This will be my first time going to the U.S.  While I'm in the U.S., I'm saying to my friend, "This is my first time being in the U.S." After I came back, I'm saying to my friend, "That was my first time going to the U.S."  Am I correct?

Comment: @J.R. Why is 1) wrong? Does it have something to do with the verb *to touch* there are examples like '[this is my first time to serve as a chairman](https://books.google.rs/books?id=XnZ_3tbpDYMC&q=%22this+is+my+first+time+to%22&dq=%22this+is+my+first+time+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=10ZCVY6eJqW67gaKwoGYDA&redir_esc=y)' or '[This was my first time to drive a car](https://books.google.rs/books?id=1WigUnNqGrMC&pg=PA156&dq=%22this+was+my+first+time+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xEdCVZK4HubC7gbj_IDYDA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzge#v=onepage&q=%22this%20was%20my%20first%20time%20to%22&f=false)' or does it depend on the context?

Comment: @tennisgirl - Those are fine, except I think you can leave out the word "being" in #2: _"This is my first time in the U.S."_

Comment: @Lucky - It's hard to explain why, but "This was my first time driving a car" sounds much more natural than "This was my first time to drive a car," which sounds like it needs a little revision, despite what Bonnie Faye Gaston may have written in her memoirs. Gaston is a self-published author with only one work to her credit. The other reference you link to is from a speech, and people bumble through speeches quite often saying things that don't come out quite right.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks :-). I guess 'this is my first time' + -ing form is one of those I'll just have to remember. Good point about self-published authors and speeches, it never occurred to me to check for that. I just took whatever Google Books threw at me as correct...

Comment: I categorically disagree with @J.R. To me, *This is/was my first time to drive a car/smoke a cigarette/have sex* is **greatly preferable** to the alternative. Likewise, Sentence 1 (with either *is* or *was*) is preferable  to Sentence 2.

Comment: Yet @Lucky see my comment above. You can't just take one person's opinion. *This is my first time to speak German* (for example) is greatly preferable to *This is my first time speaking German.* The same goes for all the other examples, as per my comment above.

Comment: @pazzo - You and I agree on this: it's best not to just take one person's opinion – especially when it's in a comment and not an answer. This place needs some diversity of opinion and healthy debate from time to time; thanks for disagreeing with me.

Comment: @pazzo - By the way, I'd probably opt for _This is the first time I've spoken in German_.

Comment: @pazzo Thanks for bringing this to my attention and for the answer :-). Things do tend to get complicated when there is more than one way to say something. But if they were simple, this site wouldn't be so interesting :-).

Comment: All three versions sound okay to me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with the sentence:

> "This is the first time I've touched a dolphin."

Then the correct way to 'rewrite' the sentence is to remain in the present perfect, *ie*

> 1a) This is my first time to have touched a dolphin.
>
> 2a) This is my first time having touched a dolphin.

Both sentences are grammatical. I greatly prefer 1a. It's hard to imagine saying 2a.

As for your original "rewrites"

> 1) This is my first time to touch a dolphin.
>
> 2) This is my first time touching a dolphin.

I also greatly prefer 1 here.

And neither 1 nor 2 have to be said at the moment of the *touch*. For example, if one is on a dolphin-spotting boat as part of an activity that lasts several hours, then either 1 and 2 can be said either before or after the actual *touch*, as part of talking about the entire experience that has (or *is*) lasting several hours. In addition, 1a can be said anytime after the actual touch. While, again, 2a seems to me unlikely to be said, and almost as unlikely to be written.

Comment: I'm getting very confused. Some textbooks say that using "to infinitive" is wrong, but here you say this is correct. The best way of saying is,"This is the first time I've touched a dolphon."  Maybe I should stick to that.

Comment: Maybe this sentence is much more complicated than I thought.

Comment: There are some verbs after which we do not use *to infinitive*, such as enjoy, discuss, dislike; there are some verbs after which we do not use the *-ing form*, such as plan, hope.